# Load formatted text from firebase and display on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a terms and condition(TOC) section on my app. What I want to achieve is to download the TOC from the internet and load it onto the screen for the user to use. Because I dont know any html/web stuff, what I am currently doing is putting all the text on my firebase with the following code to display in textView

```
    DataService.ds.REF_TERMSOFSERVICE.observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if let termsOfService = snapshot.value as? String {
            self.mainTextView.text = termsOfService
        }
    }
```

However, this method only displays the text as plain text without any formatting (New line, bold, font, font size).

I was wondering, is there a way to achieve what I want similar to image below where I can have some sort of formatting without doing some web/Html stuff? (At this stage I only know Swift)?

[image: Privacy Policy]

Comment: I just have this same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: You could try to export your text in the app as HTML and upload it to Firebase. Then if you retrieve the data you could import the HTML and display it (maybe in a WebView).